# Randomly SELECT two distinct rows on a table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| postid | value | title   |
----------------------------
| 1      | 0     | Title 1 | 
| 2      | 1     | Title 2 | 
| 3      | 1     | Title 3 | 
| 4      | 0     | Title 4 | 
| 5      | 4     | Title 5 |
```

I am trying to select two randomly distinct rows from my table. Is there a way to do it with SQL?

I've tried

```
SELECT postid
FROM table
WHERE postid > 0.9
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: your data is hard to read.  please use code ({}) tags to format it

Comment: Do you care which two rows you return?

Comment: Yes there is. Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) and we can help.

Comment: I'm confused by your data.  All 5 of your sample rows are distinct.

Comment: my code is : SELECT postid
FROM table
WHERE postid > 0.9
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 2

Comment: @user1754181 I've updated your answer to include what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT postid 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `DISTINCT` along with `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  postid,
  value,
  title
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```